# How to fix Untracked files while pushing a repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Basically, I have pushed my code to a repository on GitHub. Code has been pushed and upon checking it, I figured out that some files were missing. Then I again tried pushing with the second commit, but I got an error or warning I don't know what was that.

```
$ git commit -m "second"
On branch master
Untracked files:
        src/app/pages/
        src/app/services/
```

I was expecting that my files will be pushed, but I got stuck with this error.

Comment: do you need to `git add (path to files)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the output is from `git status`.  I don't why it's showing during your `commit` command (maybe it's something you did?) . But it's a great command; I run `git status` a lot to make sure I've added my new files and know what branch I'm on, etc.

New files within a git repository are not tracked automatically.  You just need to `git add` the files and/or directories you want:

```
git add src/app/pages src/app/services
```

Or you can add everything new in `src` (new files and files modified since their last `add`) :

```
git add src
```

When you're ready to add changes to all tracked files for a commit, that's done with:

```
git add -u # git add updated files
```

Or if you really want to add everything,

```
git add -a
```

But I always run a `git status` before . I do that.

Comment: its existence doesn't automatically track it.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the initial git remote add.

Once you've initially pushed all the data up (after committing) go ahead and run

git add .

Then recommit and push the data. Your files should then be tracked!

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that you do not have too many terminals open.

Comment: Why have too many terminals open should prevent to do a push on git remote repository?